# HttpURLConnection problems

Tags: php, mysql, json, asynchronous, httpurlconnection

i dont understand, i haven't found any problem in my code, Theoretically all my code is fine.
My server returns  json data to my app, but i dont have any response...them y chech resposeCode from the connection and its return 0.
PHP file worf fine (im try get json using my web browser and it works fine)
observation: i change the url from other webservice (the service put data into a database in mysql) and it works, the data is save into database..but the response code  its 0. Too...i have another app, in that app i have the same code to get json data and its works...returns responsecode=200. i have no idea which is the problem

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int codigoRespuesta;
TextView edit;
String err ="";
private URL servidor;
HttpURLConnection conexion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.et1);

    red a = new red();
        a.execute();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a.getCodRes(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),err,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



private  class red extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void >{

    public String getCodRes() {
        return String.valueOf(codigoRespuesta);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try{
            servidor = new URL("http://192.168.1.102/json.php?r=5&c=5");
            conexion= (HttpURLConnection)servidor.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            codigoRespuesta=conexion.getResponseCode();


        }catch (Exception a){
            err=a.getClass().toString();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe not a php problem. In case this is android problem, you might want to add that tag.

Comment: im running the app in emulator, y test a lot of apps with the same code and it works. i have 2 apps, its have a HttpURLConnection and works fine, get the correct responsecode and the json...but this app isnt work...i haven't idea which is the problem

Comment: i fixed  the problem...i just need set the correct parameters to AsyncTask(Void,Void,Integer), them set the correct type from methods doInBackground and onPosExecute. When i change that parameters y gteta 200 from my server